# How to validate using MockMvc the redirect url in the location header of a response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I'm testing an endpoint with MockMvc. This endpoints does a redirect at the end, so it's setting the redirect URL in the location header. This url has several params, so the resulting redirect url it's like this:

```
https://platform:8080/auth?scope=openid&response_type=id_token&response_mode=form_post&prompt=none&client_id=toolid&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8080/tool/token/receiver&login_hint=loginHint&state=1d73c90f-fe03-47dc-9e28-ed416fad7773&nonce=7b5e7240-161e-4d78-8e32-54923c9ce04a
```

I want to check that the 9 params are present at least. I'm thinking in something like:

```java
mockMvc.perform(get(OIDC_INIT_FLOW_ENDPOINT)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                .params(initFlowRequestParams))
        .andExpect(status().isFound())
        .andExpect(header().exists(LOCATION))
        .andExpect(header().string(LOCATION, contains("openId")));
```

This piece of code doesn't work cause the last "andExpect" but it shows my intent. How can I do achieve my goal?

EDIT:

With the help of Chris I was able to find a solution for my enquiry:

```
mockMvc.perform(get(OIDC_INIT_FLOW_ENDPOINT).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).params(initFlowRequestParams))
                .andExpect(status().isFound()).andExpect(header().exists(LOCATION)).andExpect(header().string(LOCATION,
                        Matchers.allOf(containsString("scope"), containsString("response_type"), containsString("response_type"),
                                containsString("prompt"), containsString("client_id"), containsString("redirect_uri"), containsString("login_hint"),
                                containsString("state"), containsString("nonce"))));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```java
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;

// ...
mockMvc.perform(get(OIDC_INIT_FLOW_ENDPOINT)
                 .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                 .params(initFlowRequestParams))
        .andExpect(status().isFound())
        .andExpect(header().exists(LOCATION))
        .andExpect(header().string(LOCATION, containsString("openId")));
```

My hunch is that the `contains` method you are using is a Mockito argument matcher which leads you to the wrong overload of the `string()` match method. The overload you want to use expects a Hamcrest matcher.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Now, I'm gonna ask more of you. I want to check theexistence of the 0 params in the url, I can do an "andExpect" for each param but sounds like an overkill. Hamcrest has a way to pass a list of substring in one method to check with a single call all the params?

Comment: Happy to help. *Maybe* I have made the same mistake once or twice and recognized the pattern :-). Yes, you absolutely can combine multiple Hamcrest matchers, e.g. using the [allOf matcher](https://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#allOf%28org.hamcrest.Matcher,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher%29).

Comment: Linked an outdated version of the docs, here's the [current docs for allOf](https://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/core/AllOf.html)